# When I parent mesh to bone, model will completly break

Tags: modeling, armature

Whenever I parent the mesh to bone, or bone to mesh whatever, the mesh will become way bigger, and will go sideways, i dont know why, and nobody else seems to have this problem.

Comment: can you give us a screenshot or something so the readers have more to go on?

Comment: If you [apply the scale and rotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7298/599) on the armature (and possibly the mesh) before parenting, does that help?

Comment: maybe you played with location, rotation and scale of the bones in Pose mode, in that case you need to come back in Pose mode, select all and press alt G, alt R and alt S, then you can parent?